# Invalid file error when trying to open file - Requests and Django

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I'm using requests module with Django and trying to send a file from a form but when I do I get "*invalid file :*" error when I try to open the file. I think that it's only trying to open the filename as a string instead of opening the actual file. How can I go about opening the actual file from the form instead of just trying to open the filename, so I can send it as a payload?

```
class AddDocumentView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy('users:login')
    form_class = FileUploadForm
    template_name = 'docman/forms/add-document.html'
    success_message = 'Document was successfully added'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
        file = form.save(commit=False)
        file.user = user
        if not self.post_to_server(file, user.id):
            file.delete()
        return super(AddDocumentView, self).form_valid(form)

    def post_to_server(self, file, cid):
        url = 'https://example.herokuapp.com/api/files/'
        headers = {'token': '333334wsfSecretToken'}

        # I get error here when trying to open file
        payload = {'file': open(file, 'rb'), 'client_id': cid}
        r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
        print(r.text)
        if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`open(file, 'rb')` receiving  django model object from `file = form.save(commit=False)` line, not file. send original file.
You can do something like

```
file = self.request.FILES.get('name')
self.post_to_server(file, user.id)
```

Edit:

No need to call open on the file, it's already open. `open(file, 'rb')` takes file path. the file is already open from above lines just use that. 
best practice

```
files = {'file': file}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=payload)
```

Comment: Got it. I did that but I'm getting the same error but this time it's actually recognizing the file instead of string. TypeError: invalid file: <InMemoryUploadedFile: test-file.xlsx (application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet)>